# Etherscan api on ropsten for balance checking does not work

Tags: python, api, ethereum, web3py, etherscan

I have a problem with the etherscan api on  ropsten testnetwork, the output of the code is: expecting value line 1 column 1 (char 0)

the code:

```
import requests, json

ADD = "0xfbb61B8b98a59FbC4bD79C23212AddbEFaEB289f"
KEY = "HERE THE API KEY"


REQ = requests.get(f"https://api-ropsten.etherscan.io/api?module=account&action=balance&address={str(ADD)}&tag=latest&apikey={str(KEY)}")

CONTENT = json.loads(REQ.content)
BALANCE = int(CONTENT['result'])

print(BALANCE)
```

When I try to do a request it gives back <Response [403]>

Answer (score 0):

Some websites don't allow Python scripts to access their website. You can get around this by adding a user agent in you request.

the code would look something like this:

```
import requests, json

ADD = "0xfbb61B8b98a59FbC4bD79C23212AddbEFaEB289f"
KEY = "HERE THE API KEY"
LINK = f"https://api-ropsten.etherscan.io/api?module=account&action=balance&address={str(ADD)}&tag=latest&apikey={str(KEY)}"
headers = {"HERE YOUR USER-AGENT"}

REQ = requests.get(LINK, headers = headers)

CONTENT = json.loads(REQ.content)
BALANCE = int(CONTENT['result'])

print(BALANCE)
```

To find your user agent simply type in google: my user agent